# sed: conditional merge of multiple lines

Tags: sed, merge, line

I need to merge line of a file using sed based on a pattern. eg:

Input File:

```
X1 A B C D E F

\+ G H I J 1 

\+ LK T PP E OO 2

X2 DDF F Y 

\+ J W Q
```

....

OutPut Expected:

```
X1 A B C D E F G H I J 1 LK T PP E OO 2

X2 DDF F Y J W Q 

..
```

---

I would like to equivalent of wat is possible in vi editor (:%s/\n+/ /g)

Searching the web I found a solution, which logically should have worked

> sed -e '{:a; N; s/\n+/ /g; ta}' infile

But this command defies my understanding and logic, and has produced output

```
X1 A B C D E F

\+ G H I J 1 LK T PP E OO 2
X2 DDF F Y 

\+ J W Q
```

....

Answer (score 23):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/\n+//;ta;P;D' file
```

explanation:

- `:a` is a loop placeholder
- `$!N` means if not end-of-file append next line to current line.
- `s/\n+//` means delete an end on line followed by a plus sign
- `ta` means if last substitution worked branch to `a` loop placeholder
- `P` print upto the first newline.
- `D` delete upto and including the first newline.

Comment: This saved my bacon. Netstat on Windows puts the process owning the port on a separate line from the connection state information, so I had to do this to get a MOSTLY correct list of established connections:
 iconv -f utf16le /cygdrive/c/Users/me/netstat-output.txt/System32/test.txt |  sed ':a;$!N;s/\r\n \[/ \[/;ta;P;D' | grep ESTABLISHED

Answer (score 3):

an alternative awk oneliner:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="  "}{gsub(/\n\n\+/,"")}1' yourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

potong's answer didn't work for me, but something similar works:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n+//;ta' -e 'P;D' file
```

Good sed docs here:
http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html